# how does the Internet work

Tags: router, internet

I don't quite understand how the Internet work with the IP address.
For example, there is a router in my home. With this router, I get a LAN. Also, I can connect the Internet. My question is: what is exactly the Internet here.
In my opinion, there is another higher level router, which comes from some company that offers the service of Internet, to distribute an IP address for my router. From the higher level router's point of view, all of routers, such as my router, form a bigger "LAN".
If so, I don't know how a server works. For example, everyone can login the server of google, because we know its IP address. But who gives this IP address to google? a router? If there is a router doing this, how could we recognise it?
For example, company A's router gives the IP address to google and I am using the router of company B to surf the Internet. In this case, it seems that there are two LANs: my LAN and google's LAN. How could two machines in two different LANs communicate?

Comment: There are several questions in here, and none are trivial. What have your own research brought you? Things to google could be: Internet Backbone, Router, ISP, DNS, NAT and Port Forwarding.

Comment: @Allman   I'm sorry. I'm a student, who just learnt about the web things. But what I learnt is quite simple, it's just about the ip, router etc. I tried to google but I didn't find anything like these 2 answers here.

Comment: There's also the term WAN. The Internet is a network of networks. All these LANs people have are connected with cables i.e. or e.g. telephone cables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's make it simple with a real life example:

```
(Everything in this example is based on IPv4)
```

1. Anybody can create a LAN at home/office/company, etc. That LAN must use private IP addresses, defined on [RFC1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918). This avoid the very possible conflict of having the same IP address on different places of the world.
2. Your private LAN can connect to the **public** internet through a router. The router usually has a *private* IP connected to the LAN and a *public* IP connected to the *Local ISP*. The router uses a *translation* service called **NAT** to let your *private* IP connect to the *public* internet.
3. The Local ISP uses a range of *public* IP addresses assigned by an organization known as *regional Internet registry*. **ARIN** for the United States, Canada, several parts of the Caribbean region, and Antarctica. **RIPE** for Europe, Russia, the Middle East, and Central Asia, etc.
4. The *Local ISP* uses its public IP addresses range to asign it to its client's routers and for interconnections to another ISPs, usually bigger ISPs that are connected to international ISPs. There is big mesh (a web) of interconnections regulated by **routing protocols** that calculate the *fastest* path between the router and other routers.
5. Each ISP must have two or more DNS servers, where the relationship `IP address - domain name` is stored and available for anyone to consult it. These DNS servers update their information **from and to** other high - hierarchy level DNS servers, so a change can be replicated to every DNS server on the world.
6. When **you** from your LAN want to connect to *http://www.google.com*, your PC/tablet/mobile phone/ asks the DNS server for the IP address corresponding to that name (in this case **216.58.210.164**). Then your web browser sends a request to that IP address, your local router does the **NAT** translation, send the requesting package to the ISP router, it sends it to a higher level ISP router and so on until the package arrives to *google* through the fastest or shortest path (*routing protocols*).
7. Google answers sending the page (HTML+CSS+images+cookies) to your router (again the package will go through the fastest / shortest path), your router makes the inverse **NAT** translation and puts it on the LAN and gets to your PC/tablet/mobile.

Obviously, there are a lot of technical and more complicated things happening, but this serves as a basic explanation.

Since IP is a connectionless protocol, the path from *your router to google* could be different that the path from *google to your router*, it depends on the decisions of the *routing protocols* and that is the beauty of IP /internet. If in the middle of a file transfer some intermediate router fails, the traffic re-routes using another router and the final user doesn't notice it.

If you are on Windows open a *cmd* and write `ipconfig /all` and you will see your IP, the *private* IP of your router, the IP address of the *DNS server* you are using and other information.

Also from there write `tracert www.google.com` and you can see how a requesting package from your PC travels from router to router, jumping from one ISP to another until it gets to google.

Due to the big expansion of servers and services on internet around the world there is an IPv4 addresses exhaustion. ISPs must implement IPv6 because it solves the problem and eliminates the need of **NAT** translation, making posible that the LAN use *public addresses*.

Comment: thx a lot. It helps me so much. One more thing, I want to make my pc as a server so that everyone can enter into my pc, as I know, the IP of my router is dynamic because of the exhaustion of IP4. Someone tells me that I can demand a static ip address from the ISP or I can use something like "NO-IP: free dynamic DNS". I tried to use the "NO-IP" and it tells me that my ip address is:10.*.*.*, it's a A-class IP. I'm in Luxemboug. It seems that the local ISP uses this kind of ip addresses. So in this case, I think the outer pc cant enter my pc(server) even if i used the "NO-IP dynamic DNS".

Comment: So the only thing that I can do now is: connect my local ISP?

Comment: Due to the *IP address exhaustion* some ISPs assign private address to their clients routers, so your connection is a **private LAN** behind another **private network**. In this case you can't have a *home server* as you want, because it won't be easily accesible from the public world. You will need to ask your ISP for a *public* static IP and pay an additional fee for it.

Comment: OK. I totally understand now. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 2):

> How could two machines in two different LANs communicate?

IMHO, it would be easier to understand the general rules if you first forgot about the exceptions.

First, consider that the hundreds of closed-off LANs, like the one created by your home router, are sort of an *afterthought*, which only became widespread due to shortage of IPv4 addresses.

At higher levels, beyond your home router, there is no such strict separation between "LAN" and "WAN". Instead, think of the internet as a single global network, maybe somewhat like the telephone or postal networks. There are several "tiers" of ISPs, but if you follow the hierarchy high enough, you you will not find [a single central hub](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ckIMuvumYrg) with ISPs as spokes; instead, you will find a *mesh* of interconnected networks, like in the graphs below.

[image] [image]

Your ISP, if it is large enough, will likely have multiple links to higher-tier networks, as well as direct routes to other ISPs in the same area; they all use the [BGP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol) to exchange information about what is reachable through which ISP. So if the shorter path breaks for some reason, everything will go through a longer one. <sub>*(Which seems to be happening right now between my ISP and Wikipedia. Grmh.)*</sub>

In fact, some businesses like Google or Netflix are themselves large enough to have multiple links to even tier-1 networks, which pretty much throws away any remaining hierarchy.

---

> But who gives this IP address to google?

IP addresses themselves *are* assigned in a hierarchy, starting with [IANA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority) assigning large address ranges to [regional registries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_registry), and those registries in turn give out smaller ranges to ISPs and other businesses.

But these assignments are only a *permission* to use the addresses; they have *no* relation with how the actual routers are configured. Instead, each network's operators will directly configure their own routers to use an address range they own.

(Usually the servers *themselves* will have their addresses set manually, on each server, for reliability. But it's not required – I've seen places where servers use DHCP to obtain their addresses from a router, the same way personal computers do.)

In short, IANA grants Google permission to use the address, and other ISPs worldwide make sure the address is routed towards Google's network. The rest is up to Google's network operators.

---

So, considering the above, your home router and Google's web servers are pretty much *equal members of the internet*. Each has a global IP address, which is reachable from any other place on the net by following routing tables.

- Your computer has a very simple routing table which just says that everything outside the same subnet is reachable by going through the "default gateway" (your router).
- Your home router's, similarly, just says that "LAN" IP addresses are reachable directly on the LAN ports, and everything else has to be sent towards your ISP's router.
- Here at work, we ended up having five such routers, one at every building. So their routing tables also have direct paths to every other building's router, in addition to the basic "same subnet" and "everything else" ones.
- An ISP will have several routers, some of them will have routes towards customers, some of them will know about links to other ISPs. For example, the "external" router could have such information:

  - 36.56.x.x can be reached through the ISP's own "customers" router;
  - 212.x.x.x can be reached through the 109.105.98.126 router of NORDUnet;
  - 212.162.x.x can *also* be reached through the 62.40.98.13 router of GÉANT;
  - (and so on)
  - finally, everything can be reached through Level3.

  And the "customer" router could say:

  - 36.56.1.1 can be reached through port #3;
  - 36.56.1.2 can be reached through port #4;
  - (and so on)

Whenever your computer sends a packet towards Google, or the other way around, each router will check what it can reach, and will forward the packet towards the next one. You can even see the full path by using `TRACERT` or `traceroute` commands on the terminal.

---

So those are the basics.

Yes, your home router also needs additional trickery – Network Address Translation, or NAT – to make sure your entire home network can hide behind one IP address. This is *quite* widespread: only elders such as MIT have enough IPv4 addresses to give one to every person. Almost all other networks have to settle with NAT. (My workplace owns a block of 64 addresses, but has several hundred workstations *and* students using WiFi on their phones, so most of them are behind a NAT as well.)

But, regardless of how widespread it is, NAT is still an exception, a hack to keep old things working (until IPv6 becomes more widespread in the 2100's). Most servers have a global IP address of their own, and you can reach them directly; you do not need any magic to reach within Google's network.

Indeed, if you had to connect to someone that *is* behind a NAT like yours, it could get really annoying – many games ask you to configure "port forwarding" for this reason, and peer-to-peer programs have to resort to various "hole-punching" tricks to reach inside a LAN through the NAT.

And it's going to become worse with ISPs starting to use "carrier-grade NAT", where the

---

Also, large ISPs do sometimes have more complex internals, such as policy routing, or MPLS when the route-based forwarding becomes *too* slow, but those are again just added on top of the basic IP, and should be researched separately – I haven't actually *worked* at an ISP.

Comment: thanks a lot. I love your explanation without the complex technical words.